# Group 2d array data by one column, populate subarrays with defaults, sum values from another column using a mapping array

Tags: php, arrays, sum, mapping, grouping

I am trying to group data from a 2d array while leveraging a lookup array to ensure that default values exist in each group.

My lookup/mapping array associates language ids with language names.

```
$langs = [
    5 => "english",
    10 => "french",
    12 => "german"
    ...
];
```

The other array holds the data which ahould be grouped by date value.

```
$posts = [
    [
        "date" => "13-07-2022",
        "lang_id" => 5,
        "amount" => 90,
    ],
    [
        "date" => "13-07-2022",
        "lang_id" => 10,
        "amount" => 34,
    ],
    [
        "date" => "14-07-2022",
        "lang_id" => 5,
        "amount" => 7,
    ],
    ...
];
```

Where the `$posts` have the post in that language per day. When there weren't any posts, there won't be any entry in the array.

I want to restructure the data to be grouped by date and each subarray should contain the date and the accumulated, associative language amounts:

```
$result = [
    [
        "date" => "13-07-2022",
        "english" => 90,
        "french" => 34,
        "german" => 0
    ],
    [
        "date" => "14-07-2022",
        "english" => 6,
        "french" => 0,
        "german" => 0
    ],
    ...
];
```

This is, when there no posts from the "master" list of languages, I will set that language to 0.

I tried to iterate the `$posts` and within it the `langs` array in order to fill with zeros each new processed item, but I'm failing to fulfil it.
What I tried is:

```
$d = $post[0]['date'];
$result = [];

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if ($d != $post['date']) {
        $d = $post['date'];
        $result[] = $proc;
        $proc = [];
        $proc['date'] = $d;
    }

    foreach ($langs as $id => $name) {
        if ($id == $post['lang_id']) {
            $proc[$name] = $post['amount'];
        } elseif (!isset($proc[$name])) {
            $proc[$name] = 0;
        }
    }
}

$result[] = $proc;
```

My point is if there would be a better way to achieve this with no nested loop or more efficient way

Comment: You can achieve this by first creating a template array with all languages set to 0, then looping through the $posts to fill in the values.

Comment: This is easier if the result is an associative array whose keys are the dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you loop through the posts array and for each item, first check if there is already a result for this date.  If there isn't - it adds the values from langs in using `array_fill_keys()` with a value of 0, and then adds the date in (you could make the date first by using `array_merge()`).

Then it always adds in the various keys...

$results = [];

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if (array_key_exists($post['date'], $results) == false) {
        $results[$post['date']] = array_fill_keys($langs, 0);
        $results[$post['date']]['date'] = $post['date'];
    }
    $results[$post['date']][$langs[$post['lang_id']]] = $post['amount'];
}

var_dump(array_values($results));
```

which gives...

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(4) {
    'english' =>
    int(90)
    'french' =>
    int(34)
    'german' =>
    int(0)
    'date' =>
    string(10) "13-07-2022"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(4) {
    'english' =>
    int(7)
    'french' =>
    int(0)
    'german' =>
    int(0)
    'date' =>
    string(10) "14-07-2022"
  }
}
```

For putting the date first...

```
$results[$post['date']] = array_merge(['date' => $post['date']], array_fill_keys($langs, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$langs = [
  5  => 'english',
  10 => 'french',
  12 => 'german',
];

$posts = [
  [ 'date' => '13-07-2022', 'lang_id' => 5, 'amount' => 90, ],
  [ 'date' => '13-07-2022', 'lang_id' => 10, 'amount' => 34, ],
  [ 'date' => '14-07-2022', 'lang_id' => 5, 'amount' => 7, ],
];

$langs_template = array_combine($langs, array_fill(0, count($langs), 0));

$result =
  array_values(
    array_reduce(
      $posts,
      function ($carry, $item) use ($langs, $langs_template) {
        $date = $item['date'];
        if (!array_key_exists($date, $carry)) {
          $carry[$date] = [ 'date' => $date, ...$langs_template ];
        }
        $carry[$date][$langs[$item['lang_id']]] = $item['amount'];
        return $carry;
      },
      []
    )
  );

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 13-07-2022
            [english] => 90
            [french] => 34
            [german] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 14-07-2022
            [english] => 7
            [french] => 0
            [german] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Please never script dump. Every answer should include an educational explanation. You are not new here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a default values array to be used for each date group before looping
2. Loop over the posts array
3. Use `extract()` to generate convenient temporary variables for each iteration
4. If an encountered date is new, set the default values
5. Add the current amount to the correct language column leveraging the lookup array

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Run1r))

```
$defaults = array_fill_keys($langs, 0);
$result = [];
foreach ($posts as $row) {
    extract($row);
    $result[$date] ??= ['date' => $date] + $defaults;
    $result[$date][$langs[$lang_id]] += $amount;
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

---

To avoid reindexing the result after the loop, push references into the result. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/dBl1b)

```
$defaults = array_fill_keys($langs, 0);
$result = [];
foreach ($posts as $row) {
    extract($row);
    if (!isset($ref[$date])) {
        $ref[$date] = ['date' => $date] + $defaults;
        $result[] = &$ref[$date];
    }
    $ref[$date][$langs[$lang_id]] += $amount;
}
var_export($result);
```